# Good open source OPC software

Tags: open-source, opc, plc

We are currently using a free trail version of KEP Server for our OPC to communicate with our PLC. We were wondering if anyone knows of any good open source OPC software.

Comment: Which PLCs are you using? If it is Siemens S5/S7 and you got their WinCC visualisation software installed, there's already an OPC server integrated without additional charge.

Comment: There are several nowadays on github.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Can you point out a few?

Comment: @user1496984 I am looking at https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua

Comment: If you don't strictly need OPC and your PLCs support Modbus RTU, you could try [unserver](https://unserver.xyz) - it provides a simple HTTP API  to talk to devices. It's free for non-commercial use, but unfortunately it's not open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some vendors offer OPC servers for free with their PLCs, but I haven't seen any free OPC servers that supports multiple vendors like KepWare OPC server does. Neither free (unless you count time limited ones), neither open source ones. That saying, the best bet you can get is to get Delphi and make your own OPC servers and clients with free sources found [here](http://www.opcconnect.com/delphi.php). I am not aware of free OPC server sources for other languages.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind skipping the OPC server and communicating directly with the PLC you should have a look at [libnodave](http://libnodave.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Libnodave supports only Siemens S7 PLCs.